# Emulate an Interactive SSH client using Paramiko / Twisted

Tags: python, ssh, twisted, paramiko, twisted.conch

I need to emulate SSH client and log the entered commands.

I have followed different links but most of the examples are related to **automating tasks**. For testing purpose, I need to emulate an **Interative** SSH Session and **log** commands.

Note: Paramiko is not mandatory. Twisted resources are much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Channel.get_pty`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.get_pty) and [`Channel.invoke_shell`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.invoke_shell) to simulate an interactive SSH terminal session.

```
sshClient = paramiko.SSHClient()
sshClient.connect(host, username=user, password=pass)
channel = sshClient.get_transport().open_session()

# Open interactive SSH session
channel.get_pty()
channel.invoke_shell()

print('Executing command 1')    
channel.send('command 1\n')

print('Executing command 2')
channel.send('command 2\n')
```